# How to place a tailwind transition class in Vue3

Tags: css, vue.js, tailwind-css

So i have a login form, and then

```
<template>
  <div name="container forms" class="flex h-screen flex-col items-center justify-center">
    <div
      class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center gap-2 rounded-xl border-2 border-gray-300 p-5 shadow-xl transition-all"
    >
                    ... form ...


      <div class="flex items-center justify-center gap-2">
        <div>Dont hava an account yet?</div>
        <Icon
          icon="material-symbols:keyboard-double-arrow-down-rounded"
          @click="showSignUpForm()"
        />
      </div>

      <div v-show="hasAccount" class="transition-all duration-500">
        <sign-up-form></sign-up-form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

When the user doesnt have an account, i want to show registration form. But i want to show it with animation/ transition. I tried adding "transition-all duration:500" on diffrent elements and it didnt work? Where should i put this property to animate the occurance of the registration form? How do i know this in the future?

Comment: maybe this would help [Vue Tranisition](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/transition.html)

Comment: thanks sir for the answer. I know it exists, but i like to take advantage of simplicty of of tailwind and i am not sure if i need create transition manulally. Can i use tailwind or in this situation only vue transition?

Comment: yes, you can. but if you use `v-if` or `v-show` you have to use `<Transition>` component. but if you use pure tailwind, you can do it in tailwind. something like add class `opacity-0` if `hasAccount` is false and remove class `opacity-0` if `hasAccount` is true. i'm generalizing but  you can do something like this.